# Ubuntu display warning before shutdown over ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote-access

Ok I admit it...

I stupidly shutdown my remote server via ssh instead of restarting it like I wanted to do :(

To prevent me doing a silly again, is there a way to display a warning / confirmation on a shutdown command? (like "Are you sure you want to shut down this server?" yes/no )

OR, can I not allow shutting down (but not restarting because I still might need to do that from time to time) over ssh?

Comment: Are you also going to disable `halt`, `telinit` and other methods to shutdown?

Comment: Well no. I just want to idiot proof it from myself. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`molly-guard`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=molly-guard):

```
protects machines from accidental shutdowns/reboots
```

Comment: how good: One of the scripts checks for existing SSH sessions. If any of the four commands are called interactively over an SSH session, the shell script prompts you to enter the name of the host you wish to shut down. This should adequately prevent you from accidental shutdowns and reboots.

Comment: Awesome! That exactly the kind of thing I was looking for... :)

Answer (score 2):

you could alias the shutdown command from your account, edit

```
/home/username/.bashrc
```

add

```
function savemefromlookingstupid(){
    echo 'Are you sure you wanna SHUTDOWN? [n]'
    read yesno
    if [ $yesno == y ]; then
        sudo /usr/sbin/shutdown -h now
        exit 1
    fi
    echo 'Thought so.. watch it, that was close..'
}
alias restart_server='sudo /user/sbin/shutdown -r now'
alias shutdown='savemefromlookingstupid'
```

To restart, you would run "restart_server"

Comment: Not sure there it is wise to set up an alias.  What happens when you are on some other system that doesn't have the alias?  I think it is better to simply learn to be cautious about what commands you issue while logged in as root.  There are tons of other things you can do to make a mess of things.

Comment: @Zoredache you do make a good point. I now have to head into the remote location today to press a switch... so you can consider my lesson learnt! (I think I still will create the alias though)

Comment: well, its ubuntu, so no root.. but I see your point. If you really wanted to save yourself, you would rename the binary itself.. I went the less invasive route. The question was about getting a warning though, and I got to play with scripting.. which I like ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a rule always pass time argument to shutdown:

```
# shutdown -h +2
```

Then you can cancel shutdown within 2 minutes:

```
# shutdown -c
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to set up an alias. The "reboot" command is fairly standard on linux. Stop using the shutdown command... use `reboot`.